# How to chose the "right" constructor for Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#

When using .NET's `Activator.CreateInstance` method, I'm passing the type and the parameters for it's constructor. Some types got several constructors like this:

```
public foo(Status status, TServiceReference listService, 
    Int32 listID, Int16 clientID)
{
    Status = status;
    ListService = listService;
    ListID = listID;
    ClientID = clientID;
}

public foo(Status status, String listServiceRegexCompare, 
    Int32 listID, Int16 clientID)
{
    Status = status;
    ListServiceRegexCompare = listServiceRegexCompare;
    ListID = listID;
    ClientID = clientID;
}
```

If at runtime the second parameter is `null`, I always want constructor one to be chosen. Is there any way I can achieve this? (Notice I'm calling `Activator.CreateInstance` for several different types and for another type the constructor might expect another count of parameters of different types of course). But again I always want the constructor which does NOT expect a string to be called, and pass a null object for that parameter.

Thank you.

Edit:

I'm calling the method like this

```
public void ActivateEvent(Object instance, EventInfo eventInfo, 
    ILoggingSupport logger, params Object[] parameter)
    {
        Delegate handler = 
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, 
                GetType().GetMethod("Handler"));

        _instance = instance;
        _eventInfo = eventInfo;
        _handler = handler;
        _logger = logger;

        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(instance, handler);

        Type eventArgsType = 
            eventInfo.EventHandlerType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        _referenceArgs = 
            Activator.CreateInstance(eventArgsType, parameter) as IComparable;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code you're using to call `Activator.CreateInstance`, which doesn't help. You might want to use reflection to find the right constructor and invoke that instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all from how you initialize your class it would seem you have two slightly different versions of the class that you've merged into one. Ie one that has a service reference and one that have a regular expression. If that's the case (that the service reference and regular expression are mutually execlusive) you should consider rewritting them to be two independent classes with a common base class. If you do that then this problem will go away.

In your code where you are calling CreateInstance you have a very generic piece of code and trying to solve a specific problem in a generic piece of code will be hard. The code eon't be generic no more. What you could do is try to solve it prior to the call. E.g have a few over loads depending on how many arguments you need to support

```
public void ActivateEvent<T1,T2>(Object instance, EventInfo eventInfo, 
ILoggingSupport logger, T1 p1, T2 p2)
{
  ...
  var parameterTypes = new []{typeof(T1), typeof(T2)};
  var arguments = new object[]{p1,p2};
  var ctor = eventArgsType.GetConstructor(parameterTypes);
  _referenceArgs = ctor.Invoke(arguments) as IComparable;
}
```

That's not using `Activator.CreateInstance` because the required type information will be deleted when you upcast your null arguments to object.